# The search field in the top bar is tiny

Tags: bug, design, search, user-experience, top-bar

Recently, the Stack Overflow search field has become tiny. This screen shot is from Mobile Safari on my iPad in portrait orientation:

[image]

The tiny search field doesn't expand when I tap in it, so it's useless. This feels like a bug.

(The amazing thing is that the search field works perfectly on my tiny iPhone, but not on my larger iPad. That's because on the iPhone it expands when tapped.)

Comment: But have you checked out our "Products"?!!

Comment: Nan..., it's because you have "too much Rep", and too many Badges, ah-ah...!

Comment: If you make the window small enough, it switches to a different layout where the search bar pops out below when you click on it, so this is only a problem for a certain range of widths.

Comment: Well, the input container does not have anything like `min-width` to prevent such situations, so the div shrinks before the breakboint mentioned by John is reached. Dunno what should be done about it.

Comment: Hey, @Oleg, have you heard of a new thing called "responsive" design? With this amazing new technology, a web developer can customize what content is displayed according to the viewport size. Thus, for small viewports where limited space is available, the site could drop out the badges, rep, and/or logo, leaving more room for the important interactive bits.

Comment: @CodyGray Ohhh, I've heard of that!, there's this one site I know, Stock Overflaw I think it's called, they used it to increase the area of product advertising while reducing the accessibility of site features.

Comment: Don't see how that is a bad thing - SO search is ... less than useful so I'm all for this feature to hide the search control (not really sure how much of my comment is a joke)

Comment: @CodyGray The site has been dropping out rep & badges while leaving the search bar full-size all through the responsive change. They finally fixed it recently, now I can see them. If there's an error it's in not properly responding to an action to expand a reduced search bar.

Comment: @CodyGray I'd probably drop the badges + rep out, yeah. An interim solution  would be defining a minimal width to avoid the input shrinking too much at the expense of creating a scrollbar to the right.

Comment: @philipxy I still have nightmares about an earlier design where the search box was always changing size as you tried to use it. Do you not remember that horrible thing? (References: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101387; https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101862) I'd rather the search box not need to expand. I don't need badges and rep displayed all the time. If there's extra room, fine, whatever, but they definitely shouldn't be crowding out stuff that's actually useful and interactive.

Answer (score 1):

Easy (Temp) Workaround using 'uBlock Origin':

```
! 2022-04-09 https://stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow.com##.mr0.-badges
stackoverflow.com##.js-products-menu.js-gps-track.s-navigation--item
```

The 1st Line blocks the Badges, and the 2nd one blocks the 'Products' Element (you have the same (x5) Link(s) (with all Sub-Elements/Links) in the Footer if you need them anyway...).

Tested on FF98. (+Win10 on Laptop/Desktop.)

---

And for Info, if anybody is "interested", here is the Full 'uBO' Script I use myself for SO:

```
! 2022-03-31 https://stackoverflow.com
! Top-Bar - Inbox: Disable Red Dot in 'Review Queues' Indicator:
stackoverflow.com###review-button > .s-activity-indicator__danger.s-activity-indicator
!>
! Make Top-Bar Unsticky when scrolling down:
stackoverflow.com,stackexchange.com,superuser.com,serverfault.com,askubuntu.com,mathoverflow.net##.js-top-bar:style(position: absolute!important;)

! 2022-04-09 https://stackoverflow.com
! Top-Bar: Disable Badges:
!stackoverflow.com##.mr0.-badges // Disabled...! (Not needed for myself.)
!>
! Top-Bar: Remove 'Products' Element: (Same/all Links in the Footer anyway.)
stackoverflow.com##.js-products-menu.js-gps-track.s-navigation--item
```

Comment: This is an iPad so I'm pretty sure I can't do that.

Comment: Yeah, well, SO is not really designed/meant to be used for the "heavy" (= "Quality") Work on Mobile Devices or Tablets... // But hum..., can't you even install any Add-ons/Extensions for a Browser when using a tablet...? (I don't know, I only use Laptop/Desktop...)

Comment: If it's not made to be used on mobile devices, why are all of the pages optimized for display on small screens, to the detriment of large screens?

Comment: Yeah, @Cody, that's why I used "really"... :wink:

Comment: The amazing thing is that the search field works perfectly on my tiny iPhone, but not on my larger iPad. That's because on the iPhone it expands when tapped.

Comment: This is some extra Tech Info about your Environment that you could include in your Qt actually...  // [Qt = Question]

Comment: @chivracq Agreed, I'll do that.

Comment: I am repressing, with admirable self-control, the usual "Badges??" joke.